# How to save variable value even if app is destroyed?

Tags: android

I am facing a problem in y code that I  am creating an audio recorder app that saves audio files but for name of the files I am using count variable and initialising it to 0 initially as below

```
static int count=0;
```

and then incrementing it for each new recording 
but the problem is that till the app is not destroyed count is working fine but after destroying the app when I am again starting the app then count is again initialised with 0 and my previous recordings are overwritten. So how to resolve this issue and make count to increment from where it left off before app was destroyed

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a database (which is probably oversized for your need) or you can persist it as preference(see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). To save:

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

  // Commit the edits!
  editor.commit();
```

and to read:

```
// Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
   setSilent(silent);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Different Storage options in Android

[image]

---

### Content Providers

[image]

- Consider the structured data added to the device from application1 is
  not accessible to another application2 present in the same device but
  the profile photo added to the device by `application1` is available to
  the `application2` running in the same device
- Consider android device as a city, the applications in it are the
  houses in the city, people in the houses(application) are the  data.
  Now content provider is like an broker in the city(android device).
  This broker provide access for the people in the city for finding
  different houses referring as the content provider in the android
  device provide access for the data in the device for different
  applications.

---

### Shared Preferences

[image]

- Consider I have an App say a Face book App which I use to log in to
  my account.
- Now the very first time I enter my username and password to get
  access to my account. Say I log out of the application an hour later
  again I use the same Face book App to login again to my application.
- I have to enter username and password again to login to my account
  and I set a theme to my application and other settings on how my app
  looks in my current phone
- This is un-necessary because consider I am using my phone to login to
  the application. So I will always use my phone to login again and
  again, thus entering my credentials again and again is more work
  shows it’s not a user friendly app
- Shared Preferences is very handy in such scenarios where I can use
  its feature to share my data in a xml file Which physically exists in
  the Android app installed in my phone which is not destroyed even if
  the app is closed. Here we can save user preferences data of the
  current application.
- As a result next time I open my app in my phone I can see the data
  automatically filled in the necessary fields and the settings are

---

### File Storage

[image]

- In Android we can use the device storage space to store the data in
  it for the applications. The type of data involves things such as a
  text file, image file, video file, audio file etc.
- As seen in the figure as we can see that there are two places we can
  do this. One way is to write the raw files into primary /secondary
  storage. Another way is to write the cache files into the
  primary/secondary storage.
- There is also difference between storing raw data and the cache data,
  the raw data once stored in memory by user has to be explicitly
  deleted by the user explicitly otherwise it would exist till then.
  Cache data stored in memory is not a permanent data because the
  system automatically deletes it if it feels there is shortage of
  memory.

[image]

**Internal Storage:**

- Consider a user in an application has stored data in internal
  storage, then only that user of that application has access to that
  data on the mobile and that data is automatically deleted when the
  user uninstalls the application. Speaking of which internal memory is
  private.
- The apps internal storage directory is stored using the name package
  name in a special place in the android file system.
- Other apps or users of current app have no access to the file set by
  a particular user and a particular app unless it is explicitly made
  available to the user for readable/writable access.

[image]

---

### SQLite

[image]

- Sqlite is used to store more structured data locally in a mobile
  where the android app is running. Structured data involves as of
  which shown in the figure like a student’s information in the form of
  rows and columns.
- Sqlite offers similar functionality like Mysql and oracle but with
  limited functional features. Some of the things involve performing
  query operations on tables. There are features though like creating
  views but also some features are not available like stored procedure.
- Sqlite is very helpful in storing complex and large data which can be
  downloaded once and can be used again and again until the application
  is running. When the application is closed the sqlite database is
  also destroyed.

---

### Putting all the pieces together

[image]

Answer credit - Devrath